# Installing FreePBX as a Virtual machine

Tags: openstack, pbx, freepbx

I have been trying to launch FreePBX as a VM on Openstack. The launching is successful. but the during the installation time I get the following error:Some first boot error occured and  the system is not properly setup. Check to see if you have internet access and re-run /etc/pbx_first_boot.sh.!! any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't a solution for your problem, but as a contribution to this community I can tell my FreePBX runs smoothly since 5 years as a Virtual Machine on VMWare ESXi (hosted on a local physical server Dell PowerEdge 1950) managing 100 extensions and up to 15 concurrent external channels.

Answer (score 0):

Abhishek, are you using centos or ubuntu. Try to install "PBX in a Flesh" great product and have FreePBX stable and bugfree.